# Scheduling restart of a service in Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: windows-services, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2003

How can I restart a service (i.e. once a week) in Windows Server 2003 R2?

Maybe using windows tasks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use schtask.exe:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596

It should let you set start and stop times for any service you'd like

Comment: Also, if this is a particular service (like IIS) there are other ways to have the service restarted on a schedule

Comment: It is a .net application that is installed as a service. 
Any example of schtask.exe usage? Is it a command line utility?

Comment: Do I have to create a .bat file?